# statements are ignored within MySQL query

Tags: mysql

The query below works except for the last two lines I list below.  It seems to be ignoring these lines and I'm not sure why.  I just need these combinations honored.

```
or (v_extradataclients.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND     
    v_extradatacomputers.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradataclients.`Disable SentinelOne Check` <> 1)
or (v_extradataclients.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradatacomputers.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradatalocations.`Disable ESET Check` = 1  AND 
    v_extradatalocations.`Disable SentinelOne Check` = 0))
```

The full query

```
Select Distinct
    computers.ComputerID,
    computers.Name As `Computer Name`,
    computers.Username As Username,
    computers.LastContact,
    computers.VirusScanner,
    computers.OS,
    v_extradataclients.`Disable ESET Check` As `ExtraDataClients Disable ESET Check`,
    v_extradatalocations.`Disable ESET Check` As `ExtraDataLocations Disable ESET Check`,
    v_extradatacomputers.`Disable ESET Check` As `ExtraDataComputers  Disable ESET Check`,
    v_extradatalocations.`Disable SentinelOne Check` As `ExtraDataLocations  Disable SentinelOne Check`,
    v_extradataclients.`Disable SentinelOne Check` As `ExtraDataClients  Disable SentinelOne Check`,
    v_extradatacomputers.`Disable SentinelOne Check` As `ExtraDataComputers  Disable SentinelOne Check`
From computers 
    Inner Join v_extradatacomputers On computers.ComputerID = v_extradatacomputers.computerid 
    Inner Join locations On computers.LocationID = locations.LocationID
        And computers.ClientID = locations.ClientID 
    Inner Join v_extradatalocations On locations.LocationID = v_extradatalocations.locationid
        And computers.LocationID = v_extradatalocations.locationid 
    Inner Join v_extradataclients On computers.ClientID = v_extradataclients.clientid 
    Inner Join clients On clients.ClientID = v_extradataclients.clientid
        And computers.ClientID = clients.ClientID
Where
(
    (v_extradatalocations.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradatalocations.`Disable SentinelOne Check` <> 1
    )
or (v_extradataclients.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradataclients.`Disable SentinelOne Check` <>  1
    )
or (v_extradatacomputers.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradatacomputers.`Disable SentinelOne Check` <>  1
    )
or (v_extradataclients.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradatacomputers.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradataclients.`Disable SentinelOne Check`<> 1
    )
or (v_extradataclients.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradatacomputers.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradatalocations.`Disable ESET Check` = 1  AND 
    v_extradatalocations.`Disable SentinelOne Check` = 0
    )
)
And computers.LastContact > (Now() - Interval 15 Minute)
And computers.VirusScanner Not In (312, 313)
```

Comment: If you can read it, there is so much more chance of debugging it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see,

```
   (v_extradataclients.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradatacomputers.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradataclients.`Disable SentinelOne Check`<> 1
    )
```

is a sub-case of

```
   (v_extradataclients.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradataclients.`Disable SentinelOne Check` <>  1
    )
```

In the same way,

```
   (v_extradataclients.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradatacomputers.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradatalocations.`Disable ESET Check` = 1  AND 
    v_extradatalocations.`Disable SentinelOne Check` = 0
    )
```

is a sub-case of

```
   (v_extradatalocations.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradatalocations.`Disable SentinelOne Check` <> 1
    )
```

Which explains why they're irrelevant in an OR series of conditions.

Comment: Hi Swifty, thank you for the reply.  How would I go about making these match exactly?  For

  ```(v_extradatalocations.`Disable ESET Check` = 1 AND 
    v_extradatalocations.`Disable SentinelOne Check` <> 1
    )```

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you mean (what you want to test exactly): each of your ignored statements are sub-cases of already tested statements (meaning that, if they're true, the "mother" statement is already true; you could say too that they're stronger statements). So they're unnecessary as they are; if you really need them to be verified, remove what I called the "mother" statements.